# Why is the W circle bigger than the others?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

this is my code:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt] {article}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning}
\tikzset{
    -Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
    point/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0.04cm,fill,node contents={}},
    bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex,dashed},
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped}
}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node[circle,draw] at (0,0) (X) {\bf X};
\node[circle,draw,right of=X,yshift=1cm] (Y) {\bf Y};
\node[circle,draw,right of=X,yshift=-1cm] (Z) {\bf Z};
\node[circle,draw,right of=Z,yshift=0cm] (W) {\bf W};
\draw[-] (X) -- (Y);
\draw[-] (X) -- (Z);
\draw[-] (Z) -- (W);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\caption{Un grafo semplice}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`
```

And this comes, where W is bigger than the others: [image: W bigger]

Comment: well, you are basing the circle on teh size of the content, and W is wider than X in that font (note `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex for 30 years)

Comment: Welcome! Look at the definition of `state` style: the "minimum width"  is the important bit here... (you define styles and then you don't use them, which is... surprising)

Comment: And how could I fix that? Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Add `every node/.style={minimum width=1.2cm}` (or similar) to the options of the `tikzpicture`. Unrelated, but you probably better place `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}` in your preamble to set "Figura" for all figures at once. And your MWE contains a lot of stuff that is unrelated to the output you show.

Comment: Thank you so much!